# encrypt text file using javascript

Tags: javascript, file, encryption, text

Is it possible to encrypt a text file you generate in javascript? I found a javascript file to encrypt data before it is written to the text file and it works but when i read the data back only the beginning is decrypted correctly. So I thought I should not encrypt the data in the file but the file itself. Anyone knows how to do that?

Comment: There isn't a difference between "encrypting the data in the file" and "encrypting the file itself" if the file is plain text. The problem is probably in your decryption routines. Can you add more information to your question?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't normally interact with files on the client's computer (although there are some things you can do with HTML5) so this is kinda a moot point.

Although I haven't used it, you can try [blowfish.js](http://dren.ch/js_blowfish/) which (if it matches the spec) is a very good encryption/decryption utility.